# jmx_exporter for prometheus in openshift

Tags: openshift, jmx, prometheus, javaagents

We are deploying our microservices in OpenShift. We want to monitor JMX metrics using Prometheus, in order to display them later using Grafana.

We have found the JMX_EXPORTER and as far as I understood it can be used to collect the JMX metrics in Prometheus specific format.

Now, we would like to somehow bind the agent to our code, so that we can access the metrics from inside OpenShift.

Could we somehow deploy the agent / load the agent in our Glassfish, something similar to how Jolokia works? The documentation here https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter didn't bring us too far.

Comment: It seems like you need to modify Glassfish startup script to include `-javaagent` argument.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I just spent a few hours trying to get the same done and there is very little info out there, so here is what I ended up with just in case it helps somebody.

This assumes you have prometeus agent already running in your openshift (default in 3.9)

- first activate your jmx_exporter by adding

  -javaagent:/path/to/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=8080:/path/to/jmx.yaml

to your app invocation
- the jmx.yaml can contain several things, but the most important are extraction rules - they are highly specific to your app. for example mine looks something like that:

```
startDelaySeconds: 0
ssl: false
rules:
- pattern : "kafka.consumer<type=(.+), client-id=(.+)-([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[34][0-9a-fA-F]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-fA-F]{3}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})-StreamThread-([0-9]+)(.*), topic=(.+)><>(.+): "
 name: dataplatform_$1_$7
  labels:
 clientId: "$2"
 fullClientId: "$2$5"
 clientUUID: "$3"
 threadNum: "$4"
 extraClientName: "$5"
 topic: "$6"
```

Second step is to add appropriate annotations and expose ports. Add following to your deployment yaml:

```
template:
   metadata:
      annotations:
        openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftWebConsole
        prometheus.io/path: /metrics 
        prometheus.io/port: "8080" 
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
```

and than expose the port on the container:

```
ports:
- containerPort: 8080
   protocol: TCP
```

Your prometheus should be collecting the metrics now. You should also see the metrics if you hit port 8080 on your pod.

Last step is to add Prometeus data source to your Grafana and start enjoying your metrics

Comment: @misiek...I am also trying to do same with OpenShift. My Kotlin application is running on OpenShift as well as my Prometheus. Only thing I am not understanding is, I am unable to copy jmx.jar file to target folder of my application on OpenShift. If I can do that then I will pass it with my dockerfile and run along with my application..Could you please tell me how did you don that?

Comment: Hi sorry I haven't seen your comment. Probably not relevant anymore but.. you just get the jamx_agent.jar from the maven central and copy it into your image during the build (using COPY command in the dockerfile). Not much to it really...